# "unable to find utility g++" while trying to compile a MobileSubstrate tweak with Theos (OSX)

Tags: clang, theos, cydia, cydia-substrate

OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

I recently installed Theos following [this](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup) guide, got no problems. However when I try to compile a simple MS tweak, I get this error in Terminal.app:

```
MBP:noeditnc ned$ cd /Users/ned/noeditnc 
MBP:noeditnc ned$ make
Making all for tweak NoEditNC...
Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
Compiling Tweak.xm (armv7)...
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "clang++", not a developer tool or in PATH
make[3]: *** [.theos/obj/armv7/Tweak.xm.5e67a2f0.o] Error 72
make[2]: *** [.theos/obj/armv7/NoEditNC.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [NoEditNC.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

I have Command Line Tools and Xcode both installed and updated to the latest version. Google couldn't help... What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Clang++ is installed.

```
MBP:noeditnc ned$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

EDIT 2: Found a solution! I had the wrong sdk version number in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/ (iPhoneOS8.1 instead of iPhoneOS8.2)

Comment: Looks like you need to install `clang++`

Comment: As far as I know clang is built in with Xcode, and I have Xcode installed correctly.